# git version and brew upgrade on different versions, no xcode, need fix

Tags: macos, git, terminal, homebrew

```
which git
```

gives me:  /usr/bin/git

```
git --version
```

gives me: git version 1.8.5.2 (Apple Git-48)

```
brew upgrade git
```

gives me: Error: git-1.9.0 already installed

So I ask: What's up? and How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using version of git that was installed not by brew.  Brew stores its git install in the path `/usr/local/bin/git`  You must remove the git that was not installed by brew, or change the order of your $PATHS to check `/usr/local/(bin|sbin)` first.